# how to get length of filtered array react js

Tags: reactjs

I try to display the number of cards even after it's filtered, but with this code I have only the initial number.
thanks in adavance

```js
<div>{cards.length} Results<div>

{
   cards.filter(card => {
                        if (card.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())) {
                          return card;
                      }
                    })
                      .map((card, index) => {
                        return <CardJob key={index.id}
                       
                        />
                      })
                  }
```

Comment: Assign the array to a variable and check the `.length`?

Answer (score 1):

Just do your filter before render then you'll have access to the length:

```
const filteredCards = cards.filter(card => card.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()));
```

Then :

```
filteredCards.map(...
```

Or:

```
console.log(filteredCards.length);
```